# Does max.in.flight.request.per.connection configuration makes sense for Synchronous sends?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

**max.in.flight.request.per.connection**: Controls how many message batches the producer will send to the server without receiving responses

If I am using producer in synchronous mode (where I wait for the reply before sending my next batch) does this configuration make sense? (since there can only be one in flight request at any given time)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the `max.in.flight.request.per.connection=1` achieves the same goal of ordered messages as the syn\ send.

But when you are using async producer + `max.in.flight.request.per.connection=1` it can improve performance due to batching, which is not the case with synchronus producer.